# regex: remove leading zeros, but keep single zero

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input field to which I have tied a formatting function that is triggered whenever the field loses focus.

What I aim to achieve is that I remove all the leading zeros from an input and I did achieve that with the below line. However, when the user wants to enter a single 0 or something like 0000 I still want that field to end with the value 0 (single). With `.replace(/^0+/, '')` it would remove every zero and return just an empty string. Someone knows what regex could handle this?

```
const formatNumber = ($field) => {
var number = $field.val().replace(/\./g, '').replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/^0+/, '');
return number;
};
```

**note**: `if(number === "") number = "0"` is not an option.

**edit1:**: I noticed there seems to be a bit of confusion. e.g "0009825" need to become 9825 and not 09825. the only instance where i want a 0 up front is when the value is simply zero.

Comment: use `.replace(/^0{2,}/, '');`

Comment: `.replace(/^0+/, '0')`? If you want to keep a single `0`, you should not replace all 1+ zeros at the start with an empty string, but with a single `0`.

Comment: You could also tie it the end of the string. Not sure this will work, as I am not a javascript developer, but here you match all leading zeors and any following number string. A single zero or any other number will now be matched by the second group, which you then use to overwrite the string. `.replace(/^(0+)(\d+)$/, '\2') `

Comment: @wiktor in the case of "004560" I do not want a zero up front. Only when the value entered is 0 or multiple zeros.

Comment: Then add `$`, `/^0+$/`, to tell the regex to only match a 1+ zero string

Comment: That would not remove the leading zeros in a string like "0002548"

Comment: Why not convert the input to a number and then return the number as a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You ay use this regex replacement:

```
.replace(/^(?:0+(?=[1-9])|0+(?=0$))/mg, '')
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWosbb/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start capture group

  - `0+(?=[1-9])`: Match 1 or more zeroes that must be followed by `1-9`
  - `|`: OR
  - `0+(?=0$)`: Match 1 or more zeroes that must be followed by one `0` and end
- `)`: End capture group

Replacement is empty string which will leave a single `0` if there are only zeroes in string otherwise will remove leading zeroes.

---

**Alternative solution** using a capture group:

```
str = str.replace(/^0+(0$|[1-9])/mg, '$1');
```

Answer (score 5):

A [simple reg exp](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E0%2B%28%5Cd%29%2F) with leading zeros and match one digit in a capture group

```js
const cleanZeros = str => str.replace(/^0+(\d)/, '$1')


var tests = ["0009876","0", "0000", "9999", "0090000"]
tests.forEach( s => console.log(s, cleanZeros(s)))
```